# How to set opacity animation working on Iphones?

Tags: ios, css

I want to create a simple animation on `::after` and `::before` elements and on Desktop everything works well but on iOS, on Chrome I'm getting no opacity effects.

```
@keyframes sunshine {
  from {
    opacity: 30%;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0%;
    transform: scale(4);
  }
}
```

This opacity is not working on iPhones and instead of opacity effect, I'm getting 100% background-color.

Is there any way to turn on the Alpha channel on iPhones ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to give opacity value in floating-point numbers`opacity: .3` instead of percentage values. Safari browser won't allow percentage value.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html

Comment: Nice! :) I didn't think about this, thank you very much! :)